# Slashed symbols

Tags: symbols, math-mode

In my field of work, mathematical operators that live on reduced dimensions are customarily defined as the normal one with a slash through it. For example, the gradient is usually written as `\nabla`, and if we restrict the gradient to the surface of a sphere, we usually denote it by the same symbol with a slash through it.

One way to produce a similar effect is to (ab)use the `\not` command. But as it is really built for binary relations, the slashes that it produces looks weirdly off-centre when applied to objects that are not binary relations.

Is there a better way to get slashes through arbitrary symbols?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is a package to do this, appropriately called [slashed](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/slashed).